# Firefox not downloading properly displayed blob PDF

Tags: c#, angularjs, pdf, firefox, blob

My clients are unable to download PDF document when trying to save (CTRL+S) a properly displayed PDF document in Firefox (v. 49.0.2) browser.
I dont know if this is my programming problem or a browser problem.
Only way I can download is to click on "Download" button of the PDF plugin, but my clients want to save a file with (CTRL+S) option.
Please take a look at this picture:
[image]

And there is a angular code where I try to open a file in browser: it works on Chrome and Edge, it also opens a PDF in Firefox. Response object is a $http response.

```
function openFile(response) {

        var responseHeaders = response.headers();
        var contentType = responseHeaders['content-type'];
        var contentDisposition = responseHeaders['content-disposition'];
        var fileName = contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/)[1];
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf(';')-1);
        var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: contentType });

        if(contentType==='application/pdf') //YES content-type is PDF
        {
            try
            {
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(fileURL);
            }
            catch(err) //For Edge, just save a file
            {
                FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName);
            }
        }
        else //for other content types, just save a file
        {
            FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName);
        }
    }
```

And this is my C# backend code:

```
  byte[] report = service.GetReportCustomerCreditRatesCard();//render report
        RenderFormatResolver renderResolver = new RenderFormatResolver(request.renderFormat);
        HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(report);
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = content;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(renderResolver.MIMEType);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = report.Length;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") //"attachment", "inline"
        {
           FileName = String.Format("{0}." + renderResolver.FileNameExtension,                    
Translations.REPORT_FILENAME_CUSTOMER_CARD),
           Name = Translations.REPORT_FILENAME_CUSTOMER_CARD
        };
        return response;
```

Comment: What happens if you do `CTRL+S`?

Comment: It opens Save As dialog, indicates a new download in browsers top bar and it looks like on this picture

Comment: Maybe it is because the url is not ending with `.pdf`? Here with [this pdf](http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf)  it seems to work. Is [the `Content-type` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) in your http response object set to the mime-type for pdf?

Comment: Wilt, I edited my question. I don't know how to add pdf extension to a generated blob file url. Content-type is application/pdf, otherwise Firefox would not display in PDF viewer.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Firefox, as it happens on the EDF website (EDF stands for the French electric utility company) too: I can't download the PDF invoice the first time with Mozilla Firefox. Using the `Save as` feature display the `Failed` status in the Downloads Manager. After hitting the retry button just in front of the failed download in that Downloads Manager, the file is finally downloaded properly. So I guess this is a issue in Firefox itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try once to change the content disposition header in your response object to hold also the file name:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="document.pdf"
```

So something like:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue( 'attachment; filename="document.pdf"' );
```

That might help. Not sure, but worth a try...

Comment: This code added extension to generated download file name, but there is still the same error.